# Define type of array on Restler function documentation

Tags: restler

When I define an @param as array, or the @return as array, the Explorer that comes with Restler always says `array[string]`.  Is there a way that I can specify what type of array it really is?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works in this case, but have you tried something like `int[]`? It might generate doc on `array[int]` (at least that's how PHPStorm handles docblocks on arrays of things).

Comment: I found I can use {@type in} at the end of the comment string.